# Android Indeterminate ProgressBar : Animating custom drawable

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress, android-gradient-drawable

I currently have an Indeterminate ProgressBar

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#B8A1A1"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDuration="1000"/>
```

When I set a custom drawable using a gradient of colours, the progress bar no longer moves. It's a stationary bar.

```
val colors: IntArray = intArrayOf(Color.parseColor("#a8bded"),Color.parseColor("#0a3cad"),Color.parseColor("#a8bded"))
val gd = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,colors)
progressBar2.indeterminateDrawable = gd
```

How do I make the custom progressdrawable animate as usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `useLevel=true` fixed it.

```
val colors: IntArray = intArrayOf(Color.parseColor("#a8bded"),Color.parseColor("#0a3cad"),Color.parseColor("#a8bded"))
val gd = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,colors)
gd.useLevel=true
progressBar.indeterminateDrawable = gd
```